# HTML overflow-x set focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

Currently, I have an overflow-x:scroll div, and I'd like to focus on "category_5" by default when page loading finishes.
By default, user needs to scroll to "category_5" and click "category_5". Is it possible to focus on "category_5" when the first time loading finishes?

```
<div id="category" style="overflow-x:scroll; width:100%; white-space: nowrap; height:20%;">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="category_1" width="auto" height="100%" src="icon_1_s.png" style="position: relative; top:25%;"/></a>
    <a href="index2.html"><img id="category_2" width="auto" height="100%" src="icon_2_d.png" style="position: relative; top:25%;"/></a>
    <a href="index3.html"><img id="category_3" width="auto" height="100%" src="icon_3_d.png" style="position: relative; top:25%;"/></a>
    <a href="index4.html"><img id="category_4" width="auto" height="100%" src="icon_4_d.png" style="position: relative; top:25%;"/></a>
    <a href="index5.html"><img id="category_5" width="auto" height="100%" src="icon_5_d.png" style="position: relative; top:25%;"/></a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery you can use .scrollLeft() with the position of the category 5 (.offset() or .position()). And to do it on windows load, take a look at onload event.

There are equivalents without jquery.